# how can I increase memory and cpu consumption of my machine?

Tags: c++, memory, ubuntu-12.04, cpu-usage

I want to test how my system performs when the CPU utilization is near to 99% and also the memory utilization is also near to 99%.

To increase the memory and cpu utilization to that extent can I write some code in C++ or anything?

My machine is a Ubuntu Server 12.04 with no GUI.

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/stress.1.html this ?

Comment: No need to write code, just download and run some benchmark programs or stress testers.

Comment: or http://superuser.com/questions/443406/how-can-i-produce-high-cpu-load-on-a-linux-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

```
#include <array>

const unsigned int BIG_SIZE = 50 * 1024 * 1024;

int main()
{
    std::array<char, BIG_SIZE> *m = new std::array<char, BIG_SIZE>;



    std::fill(m->begin(),m->end(),0);

    while(1)
        ;
}
```

The while loop with use 100% of a single-core CPU.

The array object will eat up the memory. You have to touch it, otherwise the OS will not really assign you that memory.

Comment: Unless you crash with a stack overflow, or the loop is optimised, or you have more than one processor.

Comment: _'The while loop with use 100% CPU.'_ I doubt this!

Comment: Your loop is single-threaded.

Comment: @HAL9000 Yes, meaning it will occupy single core processor :)

Comment: @MikeSeymour Why would it crash with a stack overflow? Only a buggy compiler would optimize that loop away.

Comment: @BЈовић: The stack overflow is because you're creating a 50MB automatic object (you could fix that using a vector rather than an array). Under the "as if" rule, the loop could be optimised to a sleep, using no CPU (you could fix that by accessing a volatile variable in the loop).

Comment: @MikeSeymour No, it is dynamically created. See the code once again :)

Comment: @BЈовић: Sorry, I didn't notice the `new` hidden in there.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Regarding endless loop - it may even be UB or implementation defined. C++ standard says that a valid program has an exit point. Endless loop has no exit point. Although I never saw it, if it is optimized away, I guess compiling without optimization would solve that issue.

Comment: Thanks BЈовић... since I have a single CPU machine so CPU usage went upto 99% but memory is still utilized upto 12%. My RAM size is 4GB

Comment: @rock Play with `BIG_SIZE`, or run several instances of the program. The code in the answer uses only 50 megabytes.

Answer (score 0):

for CPU kill i usually do something like this:

```
volatile int thread_run=0;
volatile int thread_stop=0;
DWORD __stdcall CPU_Kill_thread(LPVOID *p)
 {
 thread_run++;
 for(;!thread_stop;)
  {
  }
 thread_run--;
 }

void stop() // stop the threads before app exit
 {
 for (thread_stop=1;thread_run;) Sleep(1);
 }
```

- launch 1 thread for each CPU and set their affinity to appropriate CPU !!!

for memory Kill:

- inside main program (or thread)

  1.size=1<<20; = 1MB or whatever

  2.allocate dat=new BYTE[size]

  3.if (dat==NULL) allocate siz/2 size and stop

  4.delete dat; siz<<=1; goto 2
- now just do some memory access on whole dat[]
- do not need to access all bytes
- you can do it for every 13th byte or whatever (should be odd number just to be sure)